# Can I group by/order desc in excel?

Tags: excel

If I have a csv in the following form:

```
John,12,  
John,13,  
John,14,  
Jim,123,  
Jim,13,  
George,111
```

And I open it in excel how can I:
1) Display the names in descending order of the number of occurrences in the file? 
2) Display the numerical values ordered by number of occurences? E.g. in the trivial example 13 appears twice for Jim and John

Is it possible to do this in Excel or do I need to do it programmatically?

Comment: There is a sort feature.

Comment: create two helper columns using COUNTIF(), then sort on countif column for name, name, countif column for number, number.

Comment: Sounds like a typical case of a PivotTable to me: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-items-in-a-PivotTable-report-059b7571-55a3-4127-8990-0cf0b9b880f7 OR https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-PivotTable-report-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725 and of course making use of the `Calculated` (virtual) columns.

Answer (score 3):

Create two Helper columns using CountIF():

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

Then sort using those columns.

[image]

You can hide the count columns.

Comment: What do you mean hide the count columns. Sorry I am not very good with Excel

Comment: select both of the count columns then right click and choose hide.